# Sed doesn't work in command line however regular expression in online test regex101 works

Tags: regex, sed, command-line

I have  a string like

```
 July 20th 2017, 11:03:37.620   fc384c3d-9a75-459d-ba92-99069db0e7bf
```

I need to remove everything from the beginning of the line till the UUID substring (it's a tab, \t just before the UUID).

My regex looks like that:

```
^\s*July(.*)\t
```

When I test it in regex101 it all works beatufully: https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/1077

However, when I plonk that into a sed command it doesn't do any substitution:

```
less pensionQuery.txt  | sed -e 's/^\s*July(.*)\t//'
```

where pensionQuery.txt is a file full of the lines similar to the above. So the command above simply spits out unmodified file contnent.

Is my *sed* command wrong?

Any ideas?

Comment: the `()` needs ERE to work and not needed anyway here... `\s` won't work for all sed versions... regex syntax and features varies a lot between tools, so using regex101 for sed is not right... see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: testing a regexp in regex101 proves that that regexp works in regex101, it doesn't prove it works in sed, awk, or any other tool so YMMV with trying to use regex101 as any kind of verification tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is right, you are *not* trying `sed` with `--regexp-extended`

> `'-E'`
> `'--regexp-extended'`

> Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular
> expressions.  Extended regexps are those that `egrep` accepts; they
> can be clearer because they usually have fewer backslashes.
> Historically this was a `GNU` extension, but the `-E` extension has
> since been added to the `POSIX` standard

```
echo -e $'July 20th 2017, 11:03:37.620\tfc384c3d-9a75-459d-ba92-99069db0e7bf' |
sed -E 's/^\s*July(.*)\t//'
fc384c3d-9a75-459d-ba92-99069db0e7bf
```

Also a simple read-up on [Basic (BRE) and extended (ERE) regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html)

> Basic and extended regular expressions are two variations on the syntax of the specified pattern. Basic Regular Expression (BRE) is the default in `sed` (and similarly in `grep`). Extended Regular Expression syntax (ERE) is activated by using the `-r` or `-E` options (and similarly, `grep -E`).

Comment: `-E` doesn't appear in the current POSIX standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html. Where is that quoted text from that says "the -E extension has since been added to the POSIX standard"? `\s` is also non-POSIX btw.